# A string that eats up whatever is in front?

Tags: objective-c

I know this is a weird question but I have a string inside a RKResponse (from RestKit) that is eating whatever I add after it.

I want to know what is inside the "response.bodyAsString" that causes this behavior.

This is the code:

```
    NSLog(@"--- refreshFriendsList callback ---");

    NSLog(@"Status Code: %i",response.statusCode);
    NSLog(@"Response Contents: 54321%@12345",response.bodyAsString);

    NSLog(@"Response Contents length: %@",response.contentLength);

    if ([response isOK])
    {
        NSLog(@"RESPONSE OK");


        NSLog(@"length %lu",(unsigned long)response.bodyAsString.length);
        NSLog(@"trimmed lenght %lu",(unsigned long)[response.bodyAsString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]].length);

        NSLog(@"IS IT EMPTY? %@",[response.bodyAsString isEqualToString:@""]?@"YES":@"NO");

     .
     .
     .
```

And this is the output:

```
2013-09-04 15:26:31.958 AppName[5658:707] --- refreshFriendsList callback ---
2013-09-04 15:26:31.965 AppName[5658:707] Status Code: 200
2013-09-04 15:26:31.980 AppName[5658:707] Response Contents: 54321
2013-09-04 15:26:31.986 AppName[5658:707] Response Contents length: 4
2013-09-04 15:26:31.990 AppName[5658:707] RESPONSE OK
2013-09-04 15:26:31.997 AppName[5658:707] length 4
2013-09-04 15:26:32.002 AppName[5658:707] trimmed lenght 4
2013-09-04 15:26:32.014 AppName[5658:707] IS IT EMPTY? NO
```

As you can see the later 12345 disappeared and I have no idea why, neither why the length of the string is 4.

The server should be returning an empty string which is created from having found no results

```
JSONObject friendsAndFamilyInfo = manager.getFriendsAndFamilyList(userID);

if (friendsAndFamilyInfo != null)
{
     resp.getWriter().print(friendsAndFamilyInfo.toString());
     resp.setStatus(200);
} else
{
     resp.getWriter().print("ERROR");
     resp.setStatus(500);
}
```

UPDATE:

This is what I get when i print the response as raw data:

```
2013-09-04 15:47:59.930 AppName[5701:707] Response as Data: <007b007d>
```

And this is how restkit coverts data into a string:

```
- (NSString *)bodyAsString {
    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.body encoding:[self bodyEncoding]] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: There may be some special kind of Unicode character in your received string, like "switch to right-to-left writing system". You could try converting it to NSData and print its raw, hex values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an encoding problem: From your output

```
AppName[5701:707] Response as Data: <007b007d>
```

one can see that the returned data is the string `{}` in UTF-16 (big-endian) encoding.
If this is converted to an `NSString` using e.g. UTF-8 or ASCII encoding then the
first character of the converted string will be the NUL character.

Then in

```
NSLog(@"Response Contents: 54321%@12345",response.bodyAsString);
```

the NUL character acts as a **string terminator**.

It would also explain why the length of the string is 4: Each byte of the data is converted
to one Unicode.

**Example:**

```
uint8_t bytes[] = { 0x00, 0x7B, 0x00, 0x7D };
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
NSLog(@"%@", data);
// Output: <007b007d>
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Contents: >>>%@<<<",str);
// Output: Contents: >>>
NSLog(@"Length: %d",[str length]);
// Output: 4
```

But if the correct encoding is used:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Contents: >>>%@<<<",str);
// Output: Contents: >>>{}<<<
NSLog(@"Length: %d",[str length]);
// Output: 2
```

Comment: You are right, I just tried decoding it myself with UTF 16 encoding and I do get the appropriate {} response. I wonder why RestKit wasnt decoding it correctly if I am setting resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-16"); in the server side. Thanks!